# Sqlite and codename works on the emulator but not in my phone

Tags: sqlite, codenameone

Hello I am developing a basic mobile application using Codenameone and sqllite the problem is when trying to test my application in my phone I noticed that the application has an empty database or it is not connecting to the database while it is working correctly in the computer's emilator.
I am using this line to open or create the database:

```
db=Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("/astrax.db");
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantopenDatabaseException: unknown error code 1294 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT[1294]); could not open database
```

Here are some screenshots to make the question clearer:
[![enter image description here][1]][1][2][2]

Any advice could help, thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpewr.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YessH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is created locally and is used for debugging under the simulator. Otherwise every change you make to the database during debugging will go to all your users which isn't what you want.

If you want your app to ship with a pre-existing database check out the developer guide database section https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html

Specifically look for `getDatabasePath()`. You can simulate this in the debugger by deleting the content of your `~/.cn1` directory (which will remove your debug database).

Comment: Hello, yes I did fixed it, now the application is working fine in the phone, there is only one exception that's not happening in the emulator which is: android.database.cursoroutboundsException  index _1 requested, for a size of 1

Comment: I really don't see from where comes the problems, do u have any advice please

Comment: It happens only in one multibutton: and exactly in this line: rs.getString(0) and by the way rs=cursor.getRaw()

Comment: I suggest opening another question and including the applicable code specifically highlighting the line that's problematic. Without the code I can only guess. I think you're using the getString method before the first call to next.